# Bluetooth Headset not recognizing my phone as no phone

Tags: bluetooth, xiaomi, bluetooth-pairing

I've got a new Bluedio T2s headset. I use  Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro mobile phone. When connecting the bluetooth device, it's showing 'Connected (No Phone)' on my mobile phone. I can still listen to music, but can't make calls or receive and headset battery level is also not showing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a pair of headphone, not headset. In other word, it doesn't have a microphone builtin.

Hence the product probably isn't supposed to be used for communication, as in, it doesn't support HFP/HSP in Bluetooth but only A2DP.

As far as I know, Android does not have audio route written for outputting "voice" to A2DP-only device.

EDIT: You may also see if the settings of the paired item has a `Call`/`Phone Audio` checkbox in addition to a `Media Audio` one. If it does and the box is "checkable" (i.e. not greyed out), then you should be able to use it for communication by "checking" the box. After that `(No Phone)` should be gone.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I checked the product description again and it's saying that it has a microphone for receiving and making calls.

Comment: I checked the product description again and it has a builtin microphone. My bluetooth settings looks like this: http://tinypic.com/r/np4ajk/9

Comment: @MunafArnob Does toggling the `Phone audio` switch back and forth helps? Sounds like a compatibility defect in either the system of the phone or the headset.